# Proving weak limit of binomial random variables to a Poisson random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, moment-generating-functions

**The Problem:** Fix $0<\lambda<\infty$ and for integers $n>\lambda$ let $X_n\thicksim\text{Binom}(n,\lambda/n)$ and $X\thicksim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Prove the limit in distribution $X_n\overset{d}\longrightarrow X$ using moment generating functions.

**My Attempt:** First we compute the moment generating function of $X\thicksim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$. For all $t\in\mathbb R$ we have that
\begin{align}
M_X(t)&=E\left[e^{tX}\right]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{e^{tk}\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\\
&=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(e^t\lambda)^k}{k!}\\
&=e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}.
\end{align}
On the other hand, using the binomial theorem yields for all $t\in\mathbb R$ that
\begin{align}
M_{X_n}(t)&=\sum_{k=0}^ne^{tk}\binom{n}{k}\left[\frac{\lambda}{n}\right]^k\left[1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right]^k\\
&=\left[\frac{e^t\lambda}{n}+1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right]^n\\
&=\left[1+\frac{\lambda(e^1-1)}{n}\right]^n.
\end{align}
The above moment generating functions are finite for, say, all $t\in(-1,1)$ and in addition since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}M_{X_n}(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[1+\frac{\lambda(e^1-1)}{n}\right]^n=e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}=M_X(t),$$
also holds for all $t\in(-1,1)$, the continuity theorem for moment generating functions implies that $X_n\overset{d}\longrightarrow X.$

---

Do you agree with my proof above?
Any feedback is most welcomed and appreciated. Thank your for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed each step and they all look good to me, except there is a typo in the statement of the definition of the moment generating function for $X_n$ ($k$ should be $n-k$ for the exponent of $1-\lambda/n$. Also, the radius of convergence of both moment generating functions is all of $\mathbb{R}$, so why have you specified $t \in (-1,1)$?

Comment: My apologies for the delayed reply. I specified the radius of converge to apply the mentioned continuity theorem, just to be rather precise about the hypothesis. But you are correct, that was not needed. Thank you for your valuable feedback :-)